# Codeception: generating acceptance test raises exception on a parallel virtual machine

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I were just trying out the Codeception testing suite since we thought we need better testing, specially selenium tests. So I downloaded the phar archive and began to run the quick start instructions available on their website (http://codeception.com/quickstart).

The problem occurs when I have created a new suite and were going to generate an acceptance test. It just gives me an error:

```
  [Exception]
  Suite acceptance was not loaded
```

I have tried to google around to find any solution or to see if anybody have had the same exception raised but it seems that I am alone. What am I doing wrong?

The commands that I ran:

```
wget http://codeception.com/codecept.phar
php codecept.phar bootstrap
php codecept.phar generate:cept acceptance Welcome
```

Please, would someone try and guide me where to go now. How can I create a new acceptance test?

It says "Suite acceptance" so I tried to add an argument with the name "WebGuy" as it seems to be the name of the suite? But if I try to alter the number of commands it just gives me:

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Too many arguments.
```

Comment: Gotta dv because 'webguy' syntax is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Your command `php codecept.phar generate:cept acceptance Welcome` should have created a new acceptance test.

It should create the file `tests/acceptance/WelcomeCept.php`, which you can edit as needed for your test. eg,

```
<?php
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('Hello');
$I->amOnPage('test.php');
$I->see('foo');
```

Comment: Seems like there is something going on the virtual machine from parallel. Since the files is on  my host machine and I execute them via a ssh terminal within the guest OS it doesn't work. But when I download codeception on my host OS and run it there it works flawlessly.

Comment: The issue may be the capital `A` in `Acceptance`!  I copied from codeception documentation with capital `Acceptance` and it failed, but switched to `php vendor/bin/codecept generate:cest acceptance MyTest` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

this command worked for me:

```
php vendor/bin/codecept g:cest acceptance First
```